# Using CakePHP HTML Helper to compile .less client-side

Tags: css, cakephp, html-helper, less

**The scenario:**
I'm developing with Less CSS on a Cake App, and I want to compile the less files client-side as they recommend in the documentation (I'm also on a git repo with several other programmers, so I want them to be editing the less files instead of the css…which gets overwritten when I recompile):

```
  <head> 
    . . .
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less">
    <script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    . . .
  </head>
```

**The problem:**
I'm storing the less files in `webroot/css/lib`, and the less.js file in `webroot/js/vendors` and I want to use the HTML helper to build the link/script tags:

```
<?php echo $this -> Html -> css('lib/style.less'); ?>
<?php echo $this -> Html -> script('vendors/less-1.2.1.min.js');?>
```

There's no problem loading the less.js. The issue lies in that with the css helper, Cake appends '.css' to the end of the path.

The solution: … ?

Comment: off topic but i'd recommend compiling Less files on your side and serve the css file to the page.

Comment: That's what I've been doing. But I'm working on a Git repo with a bunch of other people. Compiling on my side means keeping the less files on my comp, and whenever someone else edits the CSS, I accidentally overwrite it the next time I compile

Comment: Can't you ask them to change the .less file instead?

Comment: Just edit less files, and commit less + compiled css. Have whole team work with less files only and commit same as you do: less+css. I know it's easier to use the .js compiler but on the other hand it's not very problematic to work like I described.

Comment: A better solution (circumventing the whole problem actually) is to actually make the .css file local and not commit it to source. Guaranteed to avoid conflicts/overrides in CSS edits because the devs can't commit to anything but the less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the html helper will check if there's a "?" in the filename.. if there isn't, it adds ".css" at the end:

**cake/libs/view/helpers/html.php ([ln. 356](http://api.cakephp.org/view_source/html-helper/#line-356))**

```
if (strpos($path, '?') === false) {
    if (substr($path, -4) !== '.css') {
    $path .= '.css';
    }
}
```

maybe you can trick the helper with something like this:

```
<?php echo $this -> Html -> css('lib/style.less?'); ?>
```

but I'm not sure if it will work... you might have to write the tag manually =P

Cheers

Comment: I was able to trick the HtmlHelper in CakePHP 2.0 by adding the ? to the end of the string. echo $this->Html->css('main.less?','stylesheet/less');

Comment: Thanks! The essence of my question was how to override the appending of .css to the path, so this is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

The other solution, very simple, is to include .less file without the helper :)
I don't think it makes a big difference for your project..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you like this plugin: https://github.com/BradCrumb/lesscompiler.

It's a component that automatically compiles less files to css files